# Ошибка при выполнении скрипта openpyxl в python

Tags: python

Когда я выполняю код вылетает ошибка:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extLst'
```

Мой код:

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename='t.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
print(ws)
```